# Rails Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, agile, passenger

I am completely new to Ruby and trying to learn the language. I am using the book Agile Web Development with Rails and in the chapter about creating using accounts, I keep receiving the error:

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ykj1a4971bgeEXuftslIgPErK67VTvPlTpcg//Wx8R8=", "user"=>{"name"=>"testaccount", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `salt=' for #<User:0x00000009008b70>):
  app/models/user.rb:41:in `generate_salt'
  app/models/user.rb:29:in `password='
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:43:in `new'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

Below is the code in my user.rb file:

```
require 'digest/sha2'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

  validates :password, :confirmation => true
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  attr_reader   :password

  validate  :password_must_be_present

  def User.authenticate(name, password)
    if user = find_by_name(name)
      if user.hashed_password == encrypt_password(password, user.salt)
        user
      end
    end
  end

  def User.encrypt_password(password, salt)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(password + "wibble" + salt)
  end

  # 'password' is a virtual attribute
  def password=(password)
    @password = password

    if password.present?
      generate_salt
      self.hashed_password = self.class.encrypt_password(password, salt)
    end
  end

  private

    def password_must_be_present
      errors.add(:password, "Missing password") unless hashed_password.present?
    end

    def generate_salt
      self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
    end
end
```

Any ideas what could be causing my problem. If you need more information let me know which files to list the code from.

Comment: Which versions of Ruby/Rails are you using?

Comment: Please post your User controller code.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue, I'm having the same problem, it works locally, but on production server it won't, I've tried running `rake db:reset` to no avail

Comment: Marcel - I ended up using Devise listed in the accepted comment below instead of trying to implement my own user creation system. Made things a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more I learn about Ruby and Rails, the more I realize that I don't write much of my own code.

I believe using something like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) would greatly ease your pain in encrypting your own stuff.

This is a suggestion that may assist you greatly in this problem and more to come.

Comment: Codeglot's answer is not correct, it won't keep around the salt value (see my comment). Using something like Devise would definitely be a good thing, but this could be a learning exercise for someone

Comment: turns out my actual problem was my production database, solving that fixed my issue but I like Devise it looks like it will add a lot of the future methods I planned to implement

Comment: I don't recommend using Devise or Authlogic. I tried 4 tutorials and none of them worked. The problem with using a gem is that if it doesn't work then you have no idea how to fix it. If you build your own then you can fix it. And, you actually learn rails in the process.

Comment: B Seven, what didn't work for you? There are thousands of developers that use devise on a regular basis. Including my employer, NASA. Is there anything that we can do to help? If so, post up a separate question on here, maybe we can help.

Comment: Had you run all the migrations? Did you have a field for 'salt' in the users table?

Comment: I've been using devise for the last 8 months and have never had any problems with it at all.

Answer (score -1):

It's because `salt` is not defined in that model.

You already have this:

```
attr_accessor :password_confirmation
```

What you can do is add this below that line:

```
attr_accessor :salt
```

And that should work.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to keep the salt around in the database to check that an entered password is correct when encrypted with it?

Comment: I don't have the book on hand. dbslone needs to look at the book better. They are missing how salt is getting defined.